# Proper pathing for an embedded include file

Tags: makefile, embedded-linux, header-files, kernel-module

I am trying to compile for a Kernel loadable module in an embedded target (the NXP ls1043a), but I am running into a header file not being found.

My Makefile is:

```make
export CROSS_COMPILE:=aarch64-linux-gnu-
export ARCH:=arm64
obj-m += helloworld.o
export KDIR:=linux-source-5.4.0
INC=/home/gfine/ls1043a_02142023/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work-shared/ls1043ardb/kernel-source/include
all: helloworld
    make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
  rm -f  helloworld**  

helloworld: helloworld.c
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc -I$(INC) $^ -o $@
```

and my error is:

```sh
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -I/home/gfine/ls1043a_02142023/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/workshared/ls1043ardb/kernel-source/include helloworld.c -o helloworld  
In file included from /home/gfine/ls1043a_02142023/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work-shared/ls1043ardb/kernel-source/include/linux/kernel.h:8:0,  
from /home/gfine/ls1043a_02142023/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work-shared/ls1043ardb/kernel-source/include/linux/list.h:9,  
from /home/gfine/ls1043a_02142023/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work-shared/ls1043ardb/kernel-source/include/linux/module.h:9,  
from helloworld.c:1: /home/gfine/ls1043a_02142023/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work-shared/ls1043ardb/kernel-source/include/linux/linkage.h:8:10:  
fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory #include <asm/linkage.h>
```

but I do not have **asm/linkage.h** as part of my includes and that directory does exist

in my build tree. This is generated from init.h.

What am I missing?

I have tried adding an `-I /home/gfine/ls1043a_02142023/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work-shared/ls1043ardb/kernel-source/include/asm` and that didn't change anything.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**.com. I tried to lend a hand at presenting the problem: Please check, esp. replacing `exit` with *exists*.

Comment: @greybeard: When format error message, please, use **code** formatting. Blockquote formatting doesn't preserve newlines, which makes error messages harder to read.

Comment: **Remove** `helloworld` target (`helloworld: helloworld.c`), remove the receipt which creates it (`$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc ...`) and remove dependency of `all` from that target. The receipt `make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) M=$(PWD) modules` is sufficient for ask kernel build system to build your module, which you specified in `obj-m += helloworld.o`.